# Yocto doesn't seem to fully consider my custom layer

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm following the ["Introduction to Embedded Linux" by Shawn Hymel](https://www.digikey.bg/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-4-create-custom-layer-and-image-in-yocto/aac0ab17e0c64ae482675abea00b328d). There, he creates a new layer `meta-custom`, adds an image recipe copied from `core-image-minimal.bb` and adds a password to the root user. To make the password addition effective, he removes `debug-tweaks` from `IMAGE_FEATURES`. He then proceeds to `bitbake custom-image`.

I did all of the above; the build has no errors and the startup is fine, but on the serial console I still don't get any password prompt.

Thinking there was something wrong with the login system itself, I just continued with a [following part](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-6-add-custom-application-to-yocto-build/509191cec6c2418d88fd374f93ea5dda) of the tutorial where a new simple app is defined. I can see it is compiled, but the final executable is missing from the image.

To me it seems that Bitbake does recognize `custom-image` as a recipe but ignores any customization. What is going wrong?

Maybe it would work if I had the same STM32MP157D-DK1 board used in the tutorial, but I have a TechNexion PICO-IMX7, based on NXP i.MX7, whose [instructions](https://github.com/TechNexion/tn-imx-yocto-manifest/tree/hardknott_5.10.y-stable) recommend the use of vendor-specific recipes like `imx-image-full`. Should I somehow make my image recipe based on `imx-image-full` instead? (I cannot simply `inherit imx-image-full` as it's not a .bbclass)

Here is my `build/conf/local.conf`:

```
MACHINE ??= 'pico-imx7'
DISTRO ?= 'fsl-imx-wayland'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= 'package_rpm'
#EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "1"
BASE_BOARD ?= "pi"
DISPLAY_INFO ?= "lcd"
RF_FIRMWARES ?= "qca ath-pci"
SOUNDCARD ?= "voicehat"
NFC ?= "nfc"
PA_TOKEN ?= "SbtQ_mC4fvJRA88_9jB7"

DL_DIR ?= "${BSPDIR}/downloads/"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"

# TechNexion setup-environment.sh wrapper: Further modification to bblayers.conf and local.conf
BBMASK += "meta-tn-imx-bsp/recipes-containers/docker-disk/docker-disk.bb"
BBMASK += "meta-tn-imx-bsp/recipes-containers/docker/docker-ce_%.bbappend"

# TechNexion Setup BSP Release: Further modification to local.conf and bblayers.conf

PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management"
```

`build/conf/bblayers.conf`:

```
LCONF_VERSION = "7"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-distro \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-custom \
"

# setup i.MX Yocto Project Release layers in bblayers.conf
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-imx/meta-bsp"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-imx/meta-sdk"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-imx/meta-ml"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-imx/meta-v2x"
#BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-nxp-demo-experience"

BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-browser/meta-chromium"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-clang"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-qt5"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-python2"
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-virtualization"

# setup Technexion i.MX Yocto Project Release Layers in bblayers.conf
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-tn-imx-bsp "

# setup NXP nfc release layer in bblayers.conf
BBLAYERS += " ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-nxp-nfc "
```

`sources/meta-custom/layer.conf`:

```
# We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"

# We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "meta-custom"
BBFILE_PATTERN_meta-custom = "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-custom = "6"

LAYERDEPENDS_meta-custom = "core"
LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-custom = "hardknott"
```

`sources/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb`:

```
SUMMARY = "My custom Linux image."

IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL}"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = " "

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image
inherit extrausers

# Change root password
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P 'toor' root;"
```

Comment: did you add it to `IMAGE_INSTALL`?

Comment: I've added the content of my .bb file. Does that answer your question? Should I add another file of interest?

Comment: No. Did you add your package to `IMAGE_INSTALL`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. As far as I understand `custom-image` is an "image recipe" that builds an image, it doesn't make any new packages. In particular, it simply runs a command to set the root password.
I tried adding `custom-image` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` in `custom-image.bb` but I get the error `ERROR: Task do_populate_sdk in [...]sources/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb rdepends upon non-existent task do_package_write_deb in [...]sources/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb`.

Comment: Then I would suggest to add something like ```IMAGE_INSTALL += "custom-image"``` to your layer.conf.